# Find the most frequent strings in an array in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a code which displays the most frequent strings in an array. I've written the code but something is wrong. Can you please tell me where is the mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int n,i,j,k,count=0, high=1, flag=0;
    char words[100][20],wordsOutput[100][20];

        printf("Enter number of elements to enter in an array: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("%d. ",i+1);gets(words[i]);fflush(stdin);
        }

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            count=0;
            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                if(strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(high<count){
                high=count;
                strcpy(wordsOutput[0],words[i]);
                strcpy(wordsOutput[1],"");
            }
            else if(high == count){
                flag=0;
                for(k=0;strcmp(wordsOutput[k],"")!=0;k++){
                    if(strcmp(words[i],wordsOutput[k])==0){
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0){
                    for(k=0;strcmp(wordsOutput[k],"")!=0;k++);
                    strcpy(wordsOutput[k],words[i]);
                    strcpy(wordsOutput[++k],"");
                }
            }
        }
        for(k=0;strcmp(wordsOutput[k],"")!=0;k++){
            puts(wordsOutput[k]);
        }
        if(strcmp(wordsOutput[0],"")==0){
                printf("\nNo coincident words");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Note that [`fflush`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fflush/) is  is only intended for output streams and may result in Undefined Behaviour on some platforms (although it's permitted on input streams on Linux these days).

Comment: `wordsOutput[100][20]` need initialize like `wordsOutput[100][20]={{0}}`

Comment: `gets()` has been deprecated, and removed from the latest C standard. You should use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I've found the mistake: 
"wordsOutput[100][20] need initialize like wordsOutput[100][20]={{0}}" 
@BLUEPIXY